# HI, I am struggling to run FB.api in a for loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

```
for(var i=0;i<commentObjectLength;i++){
var fbFeedID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].fbFeedID;
var OwnCommentID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].OwnCommentID;
var accessToken = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].accessToken;
var commentText = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].commentText;
alert("Hiii"); //  >>>>>>>1
        FB.api('/'+fbFeedID+'/comments','post',{
                    message: commentText,
                    access_token : accessToken
                },function(response){
                    if (!response || response.error){
                        //alert(response.error.message);
                    }else {
                        alert("Hello");//  >>>>>>>2
                        alert(response.id); //  >>>>>>>3
                    }
                });
}
```

> Now to tell in simple way ., I am expecting out in alert like 
>   
> 1-> Hiii
>   
> 2-> Hello 
> 3-> some response id 
> 4-> Hiii 
> 5-> Hello
>  6-> some resonse id
>
> But in real i am getting out like 
> 1-> Hiii 
> 2-> Hiii 
> 3-> Hiii 
> continues
>   till loop size . . . .
> 8- > Hello 
> 9-> some response id 
> 10- > Hello 
> 11-> some
>   response id continues . . .
>
> Problem is all time the last date of loop will go to facebook and
>   comment on feed. not seperatly. 
> So please any one help me solve this
>   issue. 
> I am struggling lot. (Hope every one can understand problem,
>   anything extra info needed plz ask) 
> Thakns in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

It is because the callback function will call only when facebook give the response to your request.

Therefore the loop continue to alert Hiii message until there is a callback come up.

If you want to do what you expected. You should have some checking before you post another request in your loop.